# Succession in Peano axioms

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory

In "Analysis I" - Herbert Amann states:
"The natural numbers consist of a set $ N$ , a distinguished element $0\in N$ and a function $v:N\to N^*$ with the following properties:

($N0$) $v$ is injective;

($N1$) If a subset $S$ of $N$ contains $ 0$  and if $v(n) \in S$ for all $n\in S$ then $S=N$.

From these two statements the authors hint that $v$ is a successor function and $n$ is a successor. Is there enough information for this? From these two statements I don't grasp the idea.

$N^*$ is N without element 0.

Comment: Hmm, I would expect $v(n) \neq n$ to be a criterion as well.

Comment: In that case it would be clear but it doesn't state it explicitly and I'm expecting to be implied somehow in one of the two axioms.

Comment: What is $N^*$ ?

Comment: Was (N1) supposed to say, ". . . if $v(n)\in S$ for all $n\in S$ . . ."?

Comment: the author doesn't hint anything. He merely declares that if you are working in such a context, then $v$ is usually called "successor". Your question seems to imply that you think that successor should mean something else, but we can't possibly know what you think it means so there is not much we can do.

Comment: also he doesn't say that $n$ is a successor, but that $v(n)$ is called the successor of $n$

Comment: You are right, $v(n)$ is a successor of n. I think I get it; because 0 isn't in the codomain the rest of the elements are "shifted" through $v(n)$ pointing to another element.

Comment: I read other forms of Peano axioms and many explicitly state this succession relation, that's why I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description does not hold since, trivially, if $v(0) = 0$ we could have $|S| = 1$ while $|N| > 1$.

Looking at the book [here](https://books.google.se/books?id=on6GoQjmHC0C&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=natural+numbers+distinguished+element+0+function&source=bl&ots=hSBpEqqDmC&sig=_UZL3xq6HYDApiLHneGgsJh9lyM&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZmsXEmJ3NAhUDXiwKHXzuASwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=natural%20numbers%20distinguished%20element%200%20function&f=false) (hopefully the link works) I find that $v$ is defined as

$$v: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N^X := \mathbb N \setminus \{ 0 \}$$

meaning $v(n) \neq n$, hence $v(0) \neq 0$. Then, because $v$ is injective and contains $0$, $S$ contains all elements of $\mathbb N$ and $S = \mathbb N$.

Comment: I added what $N^*$ is.